# May cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task:

> If a "shop" is deleted all references to it is set to `NULL`.

When I try to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(  
    id int Primary Key,
    shop int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TEST(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
);
```

I get an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__TEST__shop__2882FE7D' on table 'TEST' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEST(id int Primary Key, shop int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TEST(id) ON DELETE SET NULL);

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are creating a table with a reference to itself. This is not a good idea, and also this is not what you want.

For your task, you need to create *another table*, with a relationship (a foreign key) that references your first table. The foreign key must be defined properly to hold the rule that sets the child to `NULL` when the parent is deleted, like :

```
CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
```

See [this link on how to set option ON DELETE in a foreign key](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not exactly as you wish.  The following works:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (  
    id int Primary Key,
    shop int,
    FOREIGN KEY (shop) REFERENCES TEST(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
);
```

To be honest, I'm not sure why the in-line definition doesn't work.  The more important point is the action.  The `SET NULL` is not allowed, because SQL Server is very cautious about potential cycles.  However, `NO ACTION` is allowed.