# Post Repost May cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Posts_Posts_RepostId' on table
> 'Posts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE
> NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
> constraints.

---

### Attempt 1

---

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? RepostId { get; set; }
    public Post Repost { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
builder.Entity<Post>()
       .HasOne(s => s.Repost)
       .WithOne()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

---

### Attempt 2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678583/13434418

---

```
public class Repost
{
    public Repost()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post? Post { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? RepostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Repost? Repost { get; set; }
    public virtual Repost? RepostNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
builder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Repost)
                .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RepostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Posts_Posts");
        });

        builder.Entity<Repost>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Repost");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.PostId, "IX_Repost_PostId")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Post)
                .WithOne(p => p.RepostNavigation)
                .HasForeignKey<Repost>(d => d.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
```

I need to set null in the repost when I delete a post.
I can use DeleteBehavior.NoAction, but the question is, is there any way to set it automatically when the post is deleted?

### UPD

### Solution

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? RepostId { get; set; }
    public Post Repost { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Reposts { get; set; }
}
```

```
    builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Repost)
            .WithMany(s => s.Reposts)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.RepostId)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was close, it's just that with self-references, or any reference where your property name differs from the Type name you need to explicitly configure the FK:

This should work:

```
builder.Entity<Post>()
   .HasOne(s => s.Repost)
   .WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey<Post>(s => s.RepostId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

`DeleteBehavior.SetNull` isn't a valid option because SQL Server cannot resolve a that behaviour on a self-referencing FK. If you try and set up a self-referencing FK in SQL Server with a `ON DELETE SET NULL` you get the same error. By using ClientSetNull EF can issue UPDATE statements for any related entities before deleting the record.

`SetNull` can appear to work *if* the DbContext happens to have the related entity(ies) tracked when deleting the related one.

Comment: Thanks!
.HasForeignKey<Post>(s => s.RepostId) also requires an explicit indication .IsRequired(false)